# Why is this site getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null" when no script has been adjusted?

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I have not updated scripting this secondary site at work, only database product information. I am a graphic and web designer, with better knowledge of html and css, but less so of javascript.

Web page: http://westcoastnaturals.com/productsdesp.php

The error is causing the javascript section that shows the product information to not render.

```
Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
productsdesp.php:85
    at slideShow (productsdesp.php:85)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (productsdesp.php:68)
    at Function.<anonymous> (jquery-1.3.1.min.js:19)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.3.1.min.js:12)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.3.1.min.js:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery-1.3.1.min.js:19)
```

Here is the coding that it is points to for php:85:

```
$('#gallery .content').html($('#gallery a:first').find('img').attr('rel')).animate({opacity: 0.7}, 400);
```

And this is the full section.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Execute the slideShow
        slideShow();
    });
    function slideShow() {

        //Set the opacity of all images to 0
        $('#gallery a').css({ opacity: 0.0 });

        //Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
        $('#gallery a:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

        //Set the caption background to semi-transparent
        $('#gallery .caption').css({opacity: 0.7});

        //Resize the width of the caption according to the image width
        $('#gallery .caption').css({ width: $('#gallery a').find('img').css('width') });

        //Get the caption of the first image from REL attribute and display it
        $('#gallery .content').html($('#gallery a:first').find('img').attr('rel')).animate({opacity: 0.7}, 400);

        //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
        setInterval('gallery()', 5000);
    }
```

​

Is there something in that coding causing the error? Should I be looking elsewhere for the issue? I am really out of practice with javascript and my web searches aren't getting me far.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is appears as though `. attr('rel'))` is returning null. You should debug to find out why that is.

Comment: And post the HTML here if you need help debugging.

Comment: i don´t find an 'id=gallery' ...

Comment: Seems like a strong case for don't let anyone with the titles "graphic and web designer" touch the database.

Comment: @gforce301 I know how to edit an existing database and how to code HTML and CSS. I admitted I am not an expert at PHP or javascript. The last change I made to this site before this issue was on the Store Locations page, not even inside the database.

Comment: "I have not updated scripting this secondary site at work, only database product information" and yet you still managed to break it. A common misconception is that "anyone can change stuff in the DB and it won't break anything" and that's because as you say "I am not an expert at PHP or javascript". Meaning you have no real idea how what you are changing in the database will effect how the code works. Knowing "how to edit an existing database" and knowing "what will happen when I do" are very very far apart as you have now found out.

Answer (score 0):

The gallery elements seem to be missing from the page and therefore the script is failing to select the elements by their ID and Class: `#gallery .content`

if there was an element on the page (maybe an entry in the database) then the gallery would appear on the page?

Comment: I have found an archive of it working last month on WayBack Machine and there were never those elements on the page previously either.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the HTML element matching to $('#gallery .content').

Please make sure HTML elements are there something like following:

```
<div id="gallery ">
  <div class="content">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

If the js code is in common js which is included in every where, you can change your `slideShow()` function like following, to make sure the function wont hit the error:

```
function slideShow() {
        // check if gallery element is in the page first...
        if ($('#gallery .content').length < 1) return;

        //Set the opacity of all images to 0
        $('#gallery a').css({ opacity: 0.0 });

        //Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
        $('#gallery a:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

        //Set the caption background to semi-transparent
        $('#gallery .caption').css({opacity: 0.7});

        //Resize the width of the caption according to the image width
        $('#gallery .caption').css({ width: $('#gallery a').find('img').css('width') });

        //Get the caption of the first image from REL attribute and display it
        $('#gallery .content').html($('#gallery a:first').find('img').attr('rel')).animate({opacity: 0.7}, 400);

        //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
        setInterval('gallery()', 5000);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't change anything in the html file, which is why this is really confusing me.